# Find the angle $x$ in the following figure

Tags: geometry, triangles

$\triangle AGB ~is~  isósceles: \boxed{\measuredangle GAB = \measuredangle {GBA = 180^o - (ω+θ)}}(I)\\\triangle AEB: \measuredangle EAB + \measuredangle AEB+\measuredangle EBA = 180^o\rightarrow \\180^o -ω-θ+180^o-θ+ 2b+a = 180^o\therefore \boxed{ω+2θ=180^o+a+2b} (II)\\\triangle ADB: \measuredangle DAB + \measuredangle ABD+\measuredangle BDA = 180^o\rightarrow \\180^o -ω-θ+180^o-ω+ 2a+b = 180^o\therefore \boxed{2ω+θ=180^o+2a+b} (III)\\(II) in(III): ω+2θ-a-2b = 2ω+θ-2a-b \therefore \boxed{a-b = ω-θ}(IV)\\ \boxed{\measuredangle DGE = x+2(a+b)=\measuredangle GBA} (V)$

I found the following mathematical relationships but ... the final relationship is missing...

[image]

Comment: Is this diagram all that was given in the main question?

Comment: You have to find $x$ in terms of which angles?

Comment: Yes Sayan, this is ... the answer to the question is x=60 degrees

Comment: Math, the answer to the question is 60 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the point at which $DC$ and $AE$ meet. Then
$$\angle EXC = \angle DXA = 180^\circ-(\theta+b) = 180^\circ-\theta-b$$
So, from $\Delta XEC$,
$$x=180^\circ-(2b+180^\circ-\theta-b)=\theta -b$$
Now, since you already have $a-b=\omega - \theta$, you can write $(\theta -b)$ in any form (i.e., as a function of any variables you wish).

Does that help?

**Edit:** I missed the finishing blow, which Peta points out.

$$x=\theta-b=\omega -a$$
Also,
$$2(\omega -a)+(\theta -b)=180^{\circ}$$
So,
$$x=60^{\circ}$$

Comment: Sayan, finishing, $ \boxed{x=\theta -b}(VI) \\ (VI)and(IV): \boxed{\theta -b = ω-a = x}(VII) \\ (VII)and(III): 2(ω-a)+\theta-\beta = 180^o\rightarrow 2x+x = 180^o \\ \therefore \boxed{\color{red}x=60^0}$

Comment: @petaarantes You're welcome, but I can't believe I missed those finishing steps. Let me add them to my answer.

Comment: @petaarantes Actually I wasn't expecting a numerical answer :)